# Add custom category attribute in flat tables

Tags: category, magento-1, category-attribute, flat-catalog

There is an custom category attribute with code "filter_param". 
I want to use this attribute while preparing the top navigation menu and the flat tables are enabled. 
I want to access this attribute in the `function _addCategoriesToMenu` in class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer`. 
How can I do so without loading the category.

Comment: did you rebuild the indexes?

Comment: @Marius Sorry, I was looking at wrong place. I have edited my question.